# Automatically change the text width for all table environments using memoir

Tags: tables, floats, margins, memoir

I'd like to redefine the `table` environment in a document I'm writing so that the tables and captions are wider than the text block. I'm using the `memoir` class, and an example given in the manual is

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-1in}{-1in}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}

\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\end{document}
```

This behaves just as I'd like. The next step for me is to make this change automatically for all tables in my document. It seems that the `\renewenvironment` command is the right way to approach this, and I tried making this change:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\let\originaltable\table
\let\originalendtable\endtable
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]{%
    \originaltable[%
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{-1in}{-1in}%
    #1%
    \end{adjustwidth*}]%
    }%
    {\originalendtable}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}

\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\end{document}
```

This compiles without error, but the `adjustwidth*` environment doesn't seem to have any effect. I must be misunderstanding how to use `\renewenvironment`; does anyone have a suggestion for getting this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the following (re)definition for `table`:

```
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]%
  {\originaltable[#1]% \begin{table}[ht]
   \begin{adjustwidth*}{-1in}{-1in}}%
  {\end{adjustwidth*}\originalendtable}% \end{table}
```

The first argument `#1` is the optional argument for `\begin{table}`, which you now pass to `\origingaltable`.

When dealing with functions that use optional arguments, you can err on the side of caution by using the [`letltxmacro` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\LetLtxMacro{\originaltable}{\table}
\LetLtxMacro{\originalendtable}{\endtable}
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]%
  {\originaltable[#1]% \begin{table}[ht]
   \begin{adjustwidth*}{-1in}{-1in}
  }%
  {\end{adjustwidth*}\originalendtable}% \end{table}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}

\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was `\table` I was confused about in the end.

Comment: @DGrady don't forget to upvote Werner using the up arrow; this gives him 10 reputation points