# Different margins for text and figures

Tags: floats, margins, memoir

Is it possible to have it so that the text has smaller left and right margins than figures?  I am using `memoir`.

Comment: I recommend using the `geometry` package.

Comment: Would you please be more specific? What diagrams are you referring to?

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I meant the figures.

Comment: @azetina: Can I use geometry to set and reset the margins before and after every figure?

Comment: When you say reset the margins, what are you specifically talking about? Using stuff like `\makebox` or `\centering` affect the margins of the figures.

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13451/10898 and probably using an ifelse statement to determine whether or not there is a figure or not.

Comment: @azetina: That looks right. Is that solution compatible with `memoir`?

Comment: `memoir` has the `adjustwidth` environment for changing the margins locally.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74948/automatically-change-the-text-width-for-all-table-environments-using-memoir helps

Comment: The `geometry` package should not be used with `memoir`. `memoir` include its own commands to deal with these things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method described by Werner  [in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74950/11232) can be extended to `figure`s also to make captions spill outside margins. To make figures go beyond margins and keep them at center, you can use `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove demo in your file.
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\originalfigure}{\figure}
\LetLtxMacro{\originalendfigure}{\endfigure}
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][htb]%
  {\originalfigure[#1]% \begin{figure}[htb]
   \begin{adjustwidth*}{-.5in}{-.5in}
  }%
  {\end{adjustwidth*}\originalendfigure}% \end{figure}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\adjincludegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,center]{figure}
\caption{This is a one big caption that may run in to more than two lines without any trouble to us in setting more margins}\label{fig:figure-chow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I wanted!